# Redirect after sign out ajax post request always returns 401 and redirects to sign in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, devise

Working on a component that lets users close their account. After clicking "confirm" the component sends and AJAX post request which closes their account, sends an email, and responds with a 200.

```rb
  def deactivate
    if current_user.close_account!(params['reason'])
      ExactTarget::DeactivateAccountEmail.send_email(current_user)

      head :ok
    else
      head :internal_server_error
    end
  end
```

After that completes successfully it should forward them to a "farewell" page, that is accessible to logged out users

```
  sendRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const reason = this.props.reasonRequired ? { reason: this.state.reason } : null;
      await ajax.post(this.props.buttonUrl, reason);

      window.location.replace(this.props.farewellPath);
    } catch {
      this.setState({ requestHasErrored: true });
    } finally {
      this.props.closeConfirm();
    }
  }
```

However every time I'm redirected to the sign in page

[image]

It says it's trying to go to the farewell page in my weblogs

[image]

But it never even hits the `/farewell` controller action (I have a breakpoint at the top of it that gets hit when I go there manually), and it doesn't get the `401` error until after the ajax callback tries to redirect the user.

I'm totally stumped on this. Do I have to pass something else to the `window.location.replace()` function call? Or could it be that going from a component served by an Authorized Controller to a Public Controller is causing some weird race condition? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code from the whole controller that handles the farwell page? My gut is telling me we may need to see your application controller as well, but not sure until I see the farwell controller.